# How To Update/Set Object | Firebase Angular 6

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, before I start. Let me just say that i've researched and couldn't find anything that was exactly like my problem. So, my problem is, every time i try to use update, instead of just updating likes its pushing a likes array of the object {likes: 0}. I use to just use update with one parameter but now its requesting two and causing this behavior. Is there a way I can just increment the likes using update or set?

This is my function below that handles the updating.

```
updateIdCount(e) {
    let likes = this.getLikes();
    console.log(e);
    let idCountObj;

    this.db
      .list("/forum")
      .snapshotChanges()
      .forEach(val => {
        val.forEach((value: any) => {
          let newValue = value.payload.val();
          if (value.payload.val().id === e.id) {
            console.log(value.key);
            console.log("found a match, now updating");
            this.db
              .list("/forum/" + value.key)
              .update("likes", { likes: newValue.likes + 1 });
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, the solution was to use:

```
this.db.database.ref('path').update({likes: newValue.likes + 1});
```